# npm with node-sass and autoprefixer

Tags: node.js, compilation, npm, autoprefixer, node-sass

I use node-sass to compile all my Sass files to a master.css.
This works well but now I want to add prefixes. I would like to use only the npm, no Gulp or Grunt.

Here my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "watches": {
    "sass": "src/scss/**"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "sass": "node-sass src/scss/master.scss -o dist/css/ --style compressed",
    "prefix": "postcss --use autoprefixer dist/css/master.css -d dist/css/master.css",
    "dev": "rerun-script"
  },
  "author": "Jan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.1",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "clean-css": "^3.4.9",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
    "postcss-cli": "^2.5.0",
    "rerun-script": "^0.6.0",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
  }
}
```

I do not get it to run. I use autoprefixer and postcss-cli. The modules have been installed locally in the project directory. I think my "script" part is false.
How would that look right?

Answer (score 36):

```
 {
    "name": "npm-node-sass",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^6.3.3",
        "browserify": "^13.0.0",
        "cssnano": "^3.5.2",
        "jshint": "^2.9.1",
        "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
        "postcss": "^5.0.16",
        "postcss-cli": "^2.5.1",
        "watch": "^0.17.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild:css": "node-sass --include-path scss src/sass/styles.scss    public/css/styles.css",
        "build:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' < public/css/styles.css | postcss --use cssnano > public/css/styles.min.css",
        "lint": "jshint src/js/*.js",
        "build:js": "browserify src/js/main.js > public/js/bundle.js",
        "build": "npm run build:css && npm run build:js",
        "prebuild:js": "npm run lint",
        "build:watch": "watch 'npm run build' src/*"
    }
}
```

You need postcss and postcss-cli as a devDependency.

Comment: will this rebuild all files each time a file is edited?

Comment: Hello, how can I add more versions to the autoprefixer in this line?

"build:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b 'last 2 versions' < public/css/styles.css | postcss --use cssnano > public/css/styles.min.css",
For example I want to add ie11 and chrome latest version.

In my case, I use Windows, so I needed to escape the quotes like this:

"build:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b \"last 2 versions\"  < css/styles.css | postcss --use cssnano > css/styles.min.css",
Regards

Answer (score 6):

**Sass With Node Js (with Autoprefixer)**

`npm i -D autoprefixer clean-css-cli node-sass postcss-cli`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.5.1",
    "browserslist": "^4.5.4",
    "clean-css-cli": "^4.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf scss",
    "compile": "node-sass --output-style=expanded --source-map=true css/scss/main.scss css/scss/main.css",
    "prefix": "postcss css/scss/main.css --use=autoprefixer --map=false --output=css/scss/main.css",
    "minify": "cleancss --level=1 --source-map --source-map-inline-sources --output css/scss/main.min.css css/scss/main.css",
    "dev": "npm run compile -- --watch",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run compile && npm run prefix && npm run minify",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 4 version"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Terminal command to build: `npm run build`

Comment: How would you add the 'prefix' script after 'dev'  one has compiled scss? I tried it this way: 
`"compile": "node-sass --output-style=expanded --source-map=true css/scss/main.scss css/scss/main.css && npm run prefix"` but never seems to reach to the prefix script

Comment: +1 helped me a lot. But 2 notes: 1) the clean script is senseless and confuses. Mabye you have a scss folder in your project but the scripts doesn't create one. 2) for current versions of clean-css it is -O 1 (capitol oh) instead of --level=1

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have **styles.sass** file in **sass** directory. I've used something like this (my package.json):

```
{
 "scripts": {
    "c":"node-sass sass/styles.sass -o .|postcss styles.css -u autoprefixer -r",
    "w":"watch 'npm run c' sass"
 }
}
```

terminal command: `npm run w`. At this point each saving of **styles.sass** file will produce compiled and prefixed **styles.css** file automatically. I have postcss-cli, node-sass and watch packages installed globally.