# NPM Scripts Post Hook not Firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, postcss, npm-scripts

I am testing using npm scripts to eventually remove my reliance on Gulp. I am starting simply with one main custom script called `watch`. This script will ultimately run all scripts prefaced with the `watch` name; for example `watch:styles`. My `watch:styles` script will use node-sass to compile my sass files down into CSS. This works. However, my next step is creating a `postwatch:styles` script that runs the newly created `.css` files through PostCSS and Autoprefixer.

**The Problem**, though, is my `postwatch:styles` hook is never triggered to run.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "npm-scripts-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
    "watch:styles": "node-sass -w ./src/styles/main.scss ./dist/assets/styles/app.css",
    "postwatch:styles": "postcss -u autoprefixer --no-map ./dist/assets/styles/app.css -o ./dist/assets/styles/app.css"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "yarn-run-all": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 3 versions"
  ]
}
```

Any advice or suggestions as to why my post hook isn't firing? The initial `watch:styles` runs just fine. If I run `yarn postwatch:styles` manually the script runs correctly. Could there be a silent error on my `watch:styles` that is preventing the hook from firing?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `watch:styles` calls `node-sass` in watch mode, the command never returns but remains in an active state waiting for your files to change.

And since there is no positive return, `postwatch:styles` will never be called.

You should try another approach maybe [watching your files with `watch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197836/npm-with-node-sass-and-autoprefixer) or `nodemon`.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thank you!